# Python Class attribute changling

Tags: python, class

I'm newbie in Python, so...
I have this code:

```
def main():

    Obj1 = classA()
    Obj1.set_p1()
    Obj2 = classA()
    Obj1.del_p1()
    Obj3 = classA()
    classA.list.append(9)

    print(Obj1.list, Obj2.list, Obj3.list, classA.list)

class classA():

    list = []
    def set_p1(self):
        self.list.append(6)

    def del_p1(self):
        self.list = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and I have this out:
([], [6, 9], [6, 9], [6, 9])

So I'cant get this:
why
`Obj1.set_p1()`
change `classA.list`, but `Obj1.del_p1()` didn't do the same.
Why `classA.list.append(9)` didn't do anything with `Obj1.list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `self.list` to an empty list just creates a new *instance* attribute on Obj1 that hides the class attribute with the same name.

To clear the class-level list, you would need to access it via the class: `self.__class__.list = []`.

However, really both of these methods should be classmethods, since they don't access the instance at all.